# How do I open/extract .xdi file on (x)ubuntu?

Tags: compression, extract

Downloaded a bunch of books which were compressed in a .xdi file. How do I open/extract the internal data/files? I go to open, and Ubuntu does not recognize/nor is there a seemingly effective application..

Comment: Do you mind providing a sample file in order to run a test?

Answer (score 2):

XDI is a *proprietary* (closed-source) compressed format for **ISO** files (i.e disk images). You can't open/extract it directly on Ubuntu.

The format was developed and can only be created/opened/extracted with [WinArchiver](http://www.winarchiver.com/download.htm), and you can download a trial, 30-day version [here](http://www.winarchiver.com/download.htm). You *may not* need Windows though; try running it using Wine in Ubuntu.

Comment: So there is no FOSS solution? :-(

Comment: @RobertArkenin: not unless you reverse engineer it and code one yourself :(

Comment: Isn't that a little illegal?

Comment: @RobertArkenin, no, clean-room reverse engineering for compatibility is explicitly allowed, even under the DMCA.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry.